# Многомерный массив или зафиксированные указатели

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, sizeof

Ковырял код и наткнулся на такую вещь:

Вот код:

```
#include "stdio.h"
void a_f(char str[][0]) /// !!! Если менять правый индекс то программа будет выводить адреса с интервалами которые равны индексу (сейчас это зафиксированно и указатель никак не меняется!)
{
  int i = 4;
  while(i >= 0)
  {
    printf("%s - %p\n", str+i, str+i);
    --i;
  }
}
int main(void)
{
  char a[][10] = {"hello", "world", "again", "repeat", "stop"};
  printf("start:%p\nend:%p\n\n", a, a+4);
  a_f(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Не могу объяснить для чего это и зачем?
Объясните что за зверь такой!
В разных руководствах про массивы я этого не видел.

Comment: Это опечатка char str[][0]) ?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я поправил читайте комментарий в коде

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, видимо, в этом как раз его вопрос и заключается. Что за `[][0]` и почему 0.

Comment: @MaximPro  А в чем заключается вопрос? Что вы ожидаете получить, и что получаете?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow для чего это вообще нужно? Вот мой вопрос!

Comment: @MaximPro Что именно нужно?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow указание размерности указателя в параметрах функции

Comment: @MaximPro Иначе вы не сможете выполнять арифметику указателей для неполного типа.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow есть где почитать об этом полно? или это все что нужно знать?

Comment: @MaximPro А как вы сами себе представляете объявление этого параметра, соответствующего заданному аргументу?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow то же что и `void a(char arg[])` == `void a(char *arg) == void a(char arg[любое число])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас есть указатель на объект некоторого типа, как, например,

```
T *p = &obj;
```

то чтобы с этим указателем можно было выполнять арифметику указателей или разыменовывать указатель, нужно знать размер объекта, адресуемого указателем. Иначе говоря, нужно знать значение `sizeof( T )`.

Например, если имеется выражение `++p`, то возникает вопрос: насколько должно увеличиться значение, хранящееся в указателе? Очевидно, что после этой операции указатель должен указывать на место в памяти после данного объекта (или на следуюший элемент массива, если текущий объект является элементом массива), то есть значение указателя должно увеличиться на значение `sizeof( obj )` . Это означает, что размер объекта, на который указывает указатель, должен быть известен компилятору.

Поэтому для этой функции

```
void a_f(char str[][10]) /// !!! Если менять правый индекс то программа будет выводить адреса с интервалами которые равны индексу (сейчас это зафиксированно и указатель никак не меняется!)
{
  int i = 4;
  while(i >= 0)
  {
    printf("%s - %p\n", str+i, str+i);
    --i;
  }
}
```

которая вызывается с аргументом, объявленным как двумерный массив

```
char a[][10] = {"hello", "world", "again", "repeat", "stop"};
```

параметр функции, объявленный как массив, неявно приводится к типу указателя на элемент массива. В свою очередь аргумент, то есть двумерный массив `a`, преобразуется неявно к указателю на свой первый элемент.

Элементом этого двумерного массива является в свою очередь одномерный массив, имеющий тип `char[10]`Поэтому если вы имееете указатель на первый элемент этого двумерного массива, то чтобы изменить его так, чтобы он указывал на следующий, то есть на второй элемент массива, его значение должно быть увеличено на размер адресуемого элемента. Размер адресуемого элемента, то есть одномерного массива, равен `sizeof( char[10] )` . Функция должна знать размер этого адресуемого массива, чтобы правильно выполнять операции с указателями.

Таким образом параметр функции, объявленной как

```
void a_f(char str[][10]);
```

приводится к типу

```
void a_f(char ( *str )[10]);
```

то есть указателю на элемент массива.

В свою очередь массив, заданный в виде аргумента функции, также преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент. Это можно представить следующим одразом

```
char ( *tmp )[10] = a;

a_f( tmp );
```

Имея данную информацию о размере объекта (который равен `sizeof( char[10]` ), на который указывает указатель char ( *str )[10]), объявленный как параметр функции, функция может корректно вычислять выражение `str+i`, которое равно значению, хранимому в `str`, плюс значение, равное  `i * 10 * sizeof( char )`. То есть в результате указатель `str` бцдет указывать на `i`-ый элемент двумерного массива, размер элемента которого равен `10`. В этом и заключается смысл арифметики указателей.

Чтобы было более понятно, вы могли бы ввести алиас доя типа элемента думерного массива следующим образом

```
typedef char T[10];

// ...

T a[] = {"hello", "world", "again", "repeat", "stop"};
```

В свою очередь объявление функции будет выглядеть как

```
void a_f( T *str );
```

или как

```
void a_f( T str[] );
```

Эти два объявления объявляют одну и ту же функцию.

Поэтому размер объекта, адресуемого указателем будет равен `sizeof( T )`, что согласно введенному алиасу равно `sizeof( char[10] )`

Comment: Если я все правильно теперь понимаю, то в записи `char (*str)[10]` `str` - указатель на массив из 10 элементов типа `char`. Если это так то правильно ли сравнить допустим тот же самый указатель на тип `int` `int *p` с тем что я написал выше? Просто по сути если `int = 4 байтам` то массив из `char[10] = 10 байтам`. Увеличение с `int` более привычное указателями нежели с массивом чего либо. Если подвести черту то массив чего либо можно назвать особенным типом данных. Я все правильно понял?

Comment: @MaximPro Я не понял, причем здесь указатель int *p  и с чем вы его собираетесь сравнивать и зачем.

Comment: это как сравнение, не более

Comment: @MaximPro Массив - это не указатель, но в выражениях за редким рсключением, как, например, при использовании в операторе  sizeof, массив преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент.

Comment: А я и не говорю, что массив это указатель =) Но да в выражениях берется адрес первого элемента. Но при чем тут это?

Comment: @MaximPro Я просто не понимаю, что вы хотите сказать.

Comment: Я хочу так сказать как-нибудь локализовать в своем понимании эту запись, пока для меня она воспринимается неестественно

Comment: Так ладно...`char (*str)[10]` по факту мы создаем пользовательскую арифметику указателю str, правильно?! Долго думал как проще объяснить.

Comment: @MaximPro Мы ничего не создаем. Это объявление указателя. Тип элемента этого указателя char[10], то есть этот указатель указывает на символьные массивы длиной в 10 символов.

Comment: Хорошо, просто это ново для меня...не прижилось пока